# How can I apply If or Which in a multiple Line list?

Tags: replacement, conditional

I have a multiple Line list

```
 lines={Line[{{0.795984, 0.156606}, {0.838795, 0.0662333}}], 
 Line[{{0.775334, 0.139859}, {0.803718, 0.235747}}], 
 Line[{{0.230618, 0.114571}, {0.252104, 0.0169065}}]}
```

Assuming coordinate for each line is {x1,y1},{x2,y2}.
How could I apply if for all lines in the list？
For example: If x1>0.5, x1=0. and x2>0.5,x2=0.1。

Comment: Do you want to keep x1&x2 unchanged if x1<0.5&x2<0.5?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
lines /. Line[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] -> Line[{{If[x1 > 0.5, 0, x1], y1}, {If[x2 > 0.5, 0.1, x2], y2}}]
(*{
Line[{{0, 0.156606}, {0.1, 0.0662333}}], 
Line[{{0, 0.139859}, {0.1, 0.235747}}], 
Line[{{0.230618, 0.114571}, {0.252104, 0.0169065}}]
}*)
```